# Wait for Zookeeper client threads to stop

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

When `Zookeeper` client starts, it creates 2 threads: `SendThread` and `EventThread`.

On application shutdown I'd like working thread to wait for Zookeeper threads completion, but do not see anything suitable in the API.

Yet I can only call `ZooKeeper.close()` which sets connection state to CLOSED and queues "event of death" for EventThread.

From ClientCnxn:

```
public void disconnect() {    
    this.sendThread.close();
    this.eventThread.queueEventOfDeath();
}
```

Do I miss something?
Is there a way to join Zookeeper threads without modifying ZK client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No proper API exists, so finally had to do that with reflection:

```
        Field cnField = ZooKeeper.class.getDeclaredField("cnxn");
        cnField.setAccessible(true);
        ClientCnxn cnxn = (ClientCnxn) cnField.get(zoo);
        Field sendField = ClientCnxn.class.getDeclaredField("sendThread");
        sendField.setAccessible(true);
        Field eventField = ClientCnxn.class.getDeclaredField("eventThread");
        eventField.setAccessible(true);
        Thread sendThread = (Thread) sendField.get(cnxn);
        Thread eventThread = (Thread) eventField.get(cnxn);
        sendThread.join();
        eventThread.join();
```